# How to display json details in a webpage using Django?

Tags: python, json, django

I want to create a search bar on a webpage that searches for an ID in a JSON file and displays its data in a table.

My JSON file looks like this.

```
[
{
   "course_speed":"325.9\u00b0 / 9.3 kn",
   "current_draught":"5.3 m",
   "navigation_status":"Under way",
   "position_received":"0 min ago ",
   "imo":"9423841 / 246346000",
   "call_sign":"PBPQ",
   "flag":"Netherlands",
   "length_beam":"100 / 16 m"
}
]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hey Syed! You just want to parse JSON, store content for a specific IMO, and render it on a webpage. I will suggest you learn to parse JSON using python and complete the tutorial from Django official documentation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to create a view that loads the JSON file and puts the generated `dict` object in the template context e.g `render('your_template.html', {'data': json_dict})`. Then you use `data` in your template. You won't receive a full answer for all the steps here on SO. You need to make some progress and when you get stuck, ask a new question.

See [Django tutorial, part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial03/) for a simple example of how to use context variables in HTML templates.